# why some launch file have extension type foo.launch.xml?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through moveit pr2 tutorials and I see .launch.xml extension .Why do we need two extension.
For example pr2_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214568/why-some-launch-file-have-extension-type-foo.launch.xml--?/) by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-07-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roslaunch` automatically tab-completes any files with a `.launch` extension. In order for launch files that are mostly used as *includes* to not (edited) show up on those listings, they are given a second extension `.xml` (which they actually are).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-08-17**:
@gvdhoorn, you mean "... used as *includes* to **NOT** show up on those listings ...", right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-17**:
Yes, you are right. They don't show up, exactly because they don't have a `.launch` extension.